# New tab Vs New window in terminal

Tags: command-line

What is the difference between opening new tab of terminal in same window and opening new window of terminal?

Taking in consideration

1. user variable if x is defined in terminal and new tab is opened in this this terminal x is going to be passed automatically or not  in new tab
2. what about the application running it will be seen running in the same terminal or another pts ?

Answer (score 1):

Tabs and new windows don't differ a lot - they're all a new instance of an interactive shell.  There is a set of default variables which will show up in any instance of the shell : `PS1` , `USER`, `SHELL` , etc. These are all documented in the bash manual , or whichever shell you use.

If you manually declare a variable in a window , it won't be visible to new tab or new window unless you use `export` keyword.  For example, `export FOO=BAR` will make variable `FOO` visible to all new tabs or windows. If you declare it as `FOO=BAR`  , it won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. In fact, you can drag a tab outside the window, and it will popup and become its own window.

Comment: what i mean is the environmental variables and user variables of the window will be passed to new tab or new window ?

Comment: @eng_ahmed: Maybe you could add that to your question because currently it is not very clear exactly what you mean.